# python csv files read and upload

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to upload all the csv files that meet certain condition in a directory to a database. But I encounter an error at the beginning of my code.

```
  mypath = "D:\user\01367564\Project Coordinator\Database Trying\all data csv"
  csv_name_reg = r'^[0-9]{11}_HKG_[0-9]{14}_v2-0.csv$'
```

The error is below

```
File "D:\user\01367564\Project Coordinator\Database Trying\Upload_CA_Manifest.py", line 9
    mypath = "D:\user\01367564\Project Coordinator\Database Trying\all data csv"
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your path looks like it's meant to contain a Unicode character with the `\u...`. Please note that on Windows you have three options for paths:

Raw strings

```
mypath = r"D:\user\01367564\Project Coordinator\Database Trying\all data csv"
```

Escaped backslashes

```
mypath = "D:\\user\\01367564\\Project Coordinator\\Database Trying\\all data csv"
```

Forward slashes

```
mypath = "D:/user/01367564/Project Coordinator/Database Trying/all data csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there are some cool backslash escapes. A "\" inside a string plus a character(s).

Some notable ones are `"\n"` and `"\t"` which are newline and tab. A non-builtin backslash escape will be turned into the actual character in the final string. `"\\"` will turn into one "\" during, say, a print statement.

The escape Python thinks your using is the unicode escape. `"\uXXXX"`. To fix this all you need is to replace each backslash with a double backslash. `"\\"`. So this string will work: `"D:\\user\\01367564\\Project Coordinator\\Database Trying\\all data csv"`

For a full list of Python Backslash Escapes [look at the Python Docs.](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)